# My MySQL select shows only 1 result instead of all that I chose

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a problem with this mysql exercise, could someone help me so it displays all the records I want, because now it only takes a value from the column `tytul` and it gives the max, min and avg from the whole table instead of separating them and then counting the max, min and avg from each `tytul`

```
SELECT 
    filmy.tytul, 
    FORMAT(MIN(wypozyczenia.data_zwrotu-wypozyczenia.data_wypozyczenia),1) AS "min",
    FORMAT(MAX(wypozyczenia.data_zwrotu-wypozyczenia.data_wypozyczenia),1) AS "max",
    FORMAT(AVG(wypozyczenia.data_zwrotu-wypozyczenia.data_wypozyczenia),1) AS "sre", 
    COUNT(wypozyczenia.id_kopii) AS "Razy" 
FROM `filmy`,`wypozyczenia`,`kopie` 
WHERE (filmy.id_filmu=kopie.id_filmu AND wypozyczenia.id_kopii=kopie.id_kopii)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your query misses a `GROUP BY` clause at its end:

```
GROUP BY filmy.tytul
```

You should also use standard, explicit joins (with the `ON` keyword) rather than old-school, implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause); finally, I would recommend using table aliases to shorten the query and make it more readable:

```
SELECT 
    f.tytul, 
    FORMAT(MIN(w.data_zwrotu-wypozyczenia.data_wypozyczenia),1) AS min_data
    FORMAT(MAX(w.data_zwrotu-wypozyczenia.data_wypozyczenia),1) AS max_data 
    FORMAT(AVG(w.data_zwrotu-wypozyczenia.data_wypozyczenia),1) AS sre, 
    COUNT(w.id_kopii) AS razy
FROM `filmy` f
INNER JOIN `kopie` k ON k.id_filmu = f.id_filmu 
INNER JOIN `wypozyczenia` w ON w.id_kopii = k.id_kopii
GROUP BY f.tytul
```

Please note that I removed the double quotes around column aliases; in MySQL you need to use backticks for identifiers - or better yet, use identifiers that do not conflict with SQL keywords, and hence to not need to be quoted.